# AllowOverride not allowed here

Tags: apache

I have setup a virtualhost like following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  Options Includes
  AllowOverride All
</VirtualHost>
```

But always throws me

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-my-site.conf:
AllowOverride not allowed here
```

I'm a bit confused because I understand that is the right place to do it

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's because you have to put it in `<Directory>` directive.' .htaccess is per directory context, so you have to explicitly tell apache where .htaccess is allowed to be used.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  Options Includes
  <Directory "/var/www/html">
  AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You're right. thanks I forget about that. I have long time without use apache

Comment: Thats really nice one bro

Comment: I have `AllowOverride All` within the Directory directive but still get `AllowOverride not allowed` errors and a 500 Internal Server error on the site.