# My Routing.php doesnt work properly after switch from nginx to apache

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I am working on a small project on my local machine (in a *nginx* docker container) and I today was the first time when I uploaded it to my webserver and found out that it's an *apache* server.

Everything works fine, except for my router.php.

When I visit example.com/admin I get an error **404 on my apache server** but in my **nginx docker container I am getting the correct page** though.

I am getting `AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` in my `error_log_apache`

```php
<?php
//Router.php
namespace blog;

class Router 
    public function __construct(private AdminPage           $adminPage,
                                private AdminContentPage    $adminContentPage,
                                private ArticlePage         $articlePage,
                                private VariablesWrapper    $variablesWrapper,
                                private SessionManager      $sessionManager){}

    public function getPageForUrl() : Page
    {
        switch ((string)$this->variablesWrapper->getRequestUri()){
            case '/admin':
                if ($this->sessionManager->isAuthenticated()){
                    return $this->adminContentPage;
                } else {
                    return $this->adminPage;
                }
            case preg_match('/\/([A-Za-z]\w+)\/\?article\=[0-9]{1,5}/',(string)$this->variablesWrapper->getRequestUri()): //Hello_world/?article=0
            default:
                return $this->articlePage;
        }
    }
}
```

Since it probably has something to do with the configs, and I have to idea what exactly, I'll give you my default.conf which is the config for my nginx server.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.twig;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;



    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

and here is my untouched httpd.conf from my apache server
**Edit:** Apparently I have to rights to change the httpd config

```
# managed by uberspace-generate-httpd-config

<Directory /var/www/virtual/USERNAME>
AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=ExecCGI,Includes,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options +Includes
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName USERNAME.uber.space


ServerAlias blog.returnnull.de


ServerAlias www.returnnull.de


ServerAlias USERNAME.uber.space


ServerAlias returnnull.de



SuexecUserGroup USERNAME USERNAME
DocumentRoot /var/www/virtual/USERNAME/html

ServerAdmin USERNAME@uber.space

AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode


ErrorLog /readonly/USERNAME/logs/error_log_apache
LogLevel notice


RewriteEngine On

# If there is a host-specific pseudo-DocumentRoot, use it instead of the default one
RewriteCond /var/www/virtual/USERNAME/%{HTTP_HOST} -d
RewriteRule (.*) /var/www/virtual/USERNAME/%{HTTP_HOST}$1

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler  "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm-USERNAME.sock|fcgi://php-fpm-USERNAME"
</FilesMatch>

<Proxy "fcgi://php-fpm-USERNAME" max=10>
</Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is it the PHP script that causes the redirect, or Apache itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `.htaccess` file on the root of your project.

```
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

For this you need to enable rewrite module for apache you can do this for by running `sudo a2enmod rewrite` after this you need to restart apache server `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Since OP had `try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;` rather than `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;` in nginx config, that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` doesn't needed, only `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will be enough.

Comment: This seems to give me an Error 500 when I visit `/admin`, but my `default` page works. When I delete `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` I am then also getting Error 500 for my `default` page.

Comment: @tolik518 please check apache error log once `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @PrinceKumarBarnwal just checked the logs and I'm getting `.htaccess: AllowOverride not allowed here`

Comment: @tolik518 mate looks like you have not allowed override in  your host please look into this answer hope it help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508635/allowoverride-not-allowed-here

Comment: adding `RewriteBase /` at the top of your code has fixed the problem! Thank you very much!

I don't know if it was an server specific problem, but that fixed it for me. (I'll edit your answer)